# Column not visible in Safari - UiKit v.2

Tags: html, css, safari, grid, uikit

Can you help me solve this problem? One column is not visible in Safari. I tried change display of .uk-grid class to everything, change order of CSS attributes and it didn't help.

Here is the page: http://pegasproperty.impnet.cz/

Here is image with mentioned issue (big red box should be visible): [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mazafakin pohadkovy raper.

If not in the office is a habit, trust me,
in the streets I have the prestige, I go out with the truth out,
like pregnancy tests, you do not know anything about the street,
as a book with Majka Spirita and rappers from the villages,
I'll eat these shit like Nesquik,
do not rush before you grab over the lip,
I'll pull you out of the two-sixth of your brush
and you go home in the rain, these lyrics, tracks,
boards are not bullshit, I'm a problem I do not want to solve,